# Majorana Fermion Coherent States

Tags: many-body, partition-function, majorana-fermions, coherent-states

I was wondering if there are coherent states for Majorana operators, so, states that fulfill the relation
\begin{align}
  \hat{\gamma}_A |a,b\rangle &= a |a,b\rangle \\
  \hat{\gamma}_B |a,b\rangle &= b |a,b\rangle
\end{align}
where $\hat{\gamma}_A$ and $\hat{\gamma}_B$ are the real and imaginary part of a fermionic creation-/annihilation operator.

I am asking this because I would like to write down the partition function of a many-body-system of majorana fermions in a manner as it is done for bosons and fermions, so that one takes a basis of coherent states to explicitly write down the trace in
$$ Z = \text{Tr}(e^{-\beta(\hat{H} - \mu\hat{N}}) \, .$$

Has anyone already thought about this?

Comment: Yes people have thought about it. You might want to read a paper by Shankar introducing Fermionic path integrals.  arXiv:cond-mat/9307009v2

Comment: Sorry, what is a real or imaginary part of an operator?

Comment: It's just the conventional way to introduce Majoranas, look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorana_fermion if you're interested, the explanation there is sufficient imo.

Comment: @ octonion, sorry but i don't see the connection between my question and this paper.

Comment: @A G P, there is actually a section titled "Fermion Coherent States" where he develops a path integral approach to calculate the partition function you want. And this isn't just Shankar's idea, read a little further in whatever textbook you learned about bosonic coherent state path integrals and you will probably find your answer too.